# Empty SQLite Database after row inserting

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert, row

I want to store data into an SQLite database on Android with this method:

```
public void addMedicine(Medicine medicine)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, medicine.get_name());
    values.put(COLUMN_FORMAT, medicine.get_format());
    values.put(COLUMN_AMOUNT, medicine.get_amount());
    values.put(COLUMN_EXP_DATE, medicine.get_exp_date());
    values.put(COLUMN_TIME, medicine.get_time());

    db.insert(TABLE_MEDICINES, null, values);

    db.close();
}
```

The `Medicine` object i pass to the `addMedicine` method is an instance of a class i created, and it works.

When i want to select data from the `TABLE_MEDICINES` i use this function:

```
public int getMedicines()
{
    String med = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String SELECT_MEDICINES = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MEDICINES;

    // Setting cursor to the first row.

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_MEDICINES, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int tmp_count = 0;

    while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")) != null)
        {
            med += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            med += "\n";
            tmp_count++;
        }
    }

    db.close();

    return tmp_count;

}
```

I only count how many rows are in the table and set the text of a `TextView` with the `tmp_count` value. When i run the app, the `TextView` is always 0, and i think the database is empty so the row hasn't been inserted.
Anyone as any idea? Thank you all in advance!

This is my `DatabaseHandler` class so you can understand how i create the database:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DailyPill";
private static final String TABLE_MEDICINES = "Medicines";

private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
private static final String COLUMN_FORMAT = "format";
private static final String COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";
private static final String COLUMN_EXP_DATE = "exp_date";
private static final String COLUMN_TIME = "time";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

public DatabaseHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION, errorHandler);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEDICINES + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" + ", " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " VARCHAR(50)" + ", " +
            COLUMN_FORMAT + " VARCHAR(20)" + ", " +
            COLUMN_AMOUNT + " INTEGER" + ", " +
            COLUMN_EXP_DATE + " DATE" + ", " +
            COLUMN_TIME + " HOUR" +
            ");";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_MEDICINES);
    onCreate(db);

}

// The following functions adds a row to the database.

public long addMedicine(Medicine medicine)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, medicine.get_name());
    values.put(COLUMN_FORMAT, medicine.get_format());
    values.put(COLUMN_AMOUNT, medicine.get_amount());
    values.put(COLUMN_EXP_DATE, medicine.get_exp_date());
    values.put(COLUMN_TIME, medicine.get_time());

    long tmp = db.insert(TABLE_MEDICINES, null, values);

    db.close();

    return tmp;
}

// The following function gets all rows from the database.

public int getMedicines()
{
    String[] Medicines = {};
    String med = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String SELECT_MEDICINES = "SELECT " + COLUMN_NAME +" FROM " + TABLE_MEDICINES;

    // Setting cursor to the first row.

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_MEDICINES, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    /*for(int i = 0; !cursor.isAfterLast(); i++)
    {
        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME)) != null)
        {
            Medicines[i] = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME));
        }
    }*/

    int tmp_count = 0;

    while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")) != null)
        {
            med += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
            med += "\n";
            tmp_count++;
        }
    }

    db.close();

    return tmp_count;

}

public int tmp_getMedicines() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_MEDICINES, null);

    int tmp_count = cursor.getCount();

    cursor.close();

    return tmp_count;
}
}
```

And this is the function where i call the `addMedicine()` method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = null;
    switch(mPage)
    {
        case 1:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_sqltest, container, false);
            Medicine med = new Medicine("medicine1", "pill", 1, "2018-02-01", "12:30:00");
            dbHandler.addMedicine(med);
            temp_out(view, dbHandler);

            return view;
        case 2:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_settings, container, false);
            return view;
        case 3:
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_info, container, false);
            return view;
    }
    return view;
}
```

The `temp_out` method is the following:

```
public void temp_out(View v, DatabaseHandler dbHandler)
{
    output = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tmp_text);
    String num = String.valueOf(dbHandler.getMedicines());
    output.setText(num);
}
```

Comment: This is the poorest way to run a count query in SQLite. Instead, use
select count(*) from TABLE_MEDICINE;
as your query.

Comment: To be sure and not just thinking the db is empty, use adb pull to get the database from the device/emulator and inspect it, or check the return value of the insert() method. Moreover, use COUNT function of the SQL to get the number of rows.

Comment: Yes, i know, but this isn't my real intent, it is just for testing purpose.

Comment: @biegleux the method he has used to insert data is right,  he just need to make sure that the way you use this method to insert data is right.

Comment: @Apurva we can't be sure until the return value of insert() method is not -1. As inserted data may break the db's contract or there is no space etc., or if medicine.get_name() is null.

Comment: @biegleux i searched for the database in my emulated device, but it seems to not exist, the database folder is empty.

Comment: have you checked in `/data/data/your.package.name/databases/` ?

Comment: @biegleux yes, that's the folder i searched into...

Comment: Than you have no database created.

Comment: @biegleux But it should give me some kind of error, i don't understand...
Anyway, i edited the question so you can better understand!

Answer (score 0):

Your `getMedicines()` function never called `cursor.moveToNext()` and was therefore stuck in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Change your getMedicines() method as follows-

```
public int getMedicines() {
        String med = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String SELECT_MEDICINES = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_MEDICINES;

        // Setting cursor to the first row.

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_MEDICINES, null);
        int tmp_count = 0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            if (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")) != null) {
                med += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                med += "\n";
                tmp_count++;
            }
        }

        db.close();
        return tmp_count;

    }
```

**Edit:**
If you are using the android studio and you have set the adb in environment variable then you can use the following command from  terminal for see the databse on emulator and the rooted devices-

```
>adb shell
# sqlite3 /data/data/yourpackagename/databses/yourdatabasename
```

and then you can use the simple sqlite query to check the details